# What sort psychoanalytic questions are permitted?

Tags: discussion

[This](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/33393/how-do-psychoanalysts-talk-about-proof) was closed.

It's a question about the intersection between epistemology and psychoanalysis, though at root it is for psychoanalysts to answer, not a philosopher per se.

Is it off topic?

What are the rules for questions on psychoanalysis?

Comment: obvs i'm struggling to use the site, tho i'm trying to do so in a polite and interesting way

Comment: Interesting question. I was unaware anyone considered psychoanalysis a part of philosophy.

Answer (score 3):

Psychoanalysis questions broadly should be considered on-topic.

(upvote this is if you think this is the way we should go).

Comment: There are many philosophical areas of type "philosophy of discipline xxx" like philosophy of mathematics, philosophy of biology, philosophy of religion. In my opinion, philosophy of psychology should have the same status. A fundamental work from this area is *Gruenbaum, Adolph: The Foundations of Psychoanalysis. A Philosophical Critique* 1984

Comment: It seems appropriate to read perhaps as a broad "school" with relevant philosophical views (at least as regards "philosophy of love" sort of questions)

Comment: Clearly, things done in philosophy of psychology or philosophy of psychoanalysis is on topic ... but are works within psychoanalysis itself on-topic?

Comment: How would you classify Lacan and 'Critical Theorists' like him.  If these are not philosophers, then why?  What they are doing is clearly not science, it is intense observation with a totally non-scientific method.

Answer (score 2):

Psychoanalysis questions are in general off-topic here.

Most would be a better fit  for CogSci.SE

(upvote if you think this is the way we should go).

Comment: To my mind, psychoanalysis is clearly not science.  It is not 'normal science', as it does not even try to pass tests like Popper's, and it is not 'revolutionary science' because it happily coexists alongside all kinds of other paradigms.  It uses a different kind of method, more related to classical philology and literary criticism to establish credibility.  So 'cognitive sciences' would not include it.  (If Freud is psychology, then Marx goes too, as economics.)